# How to import backend exported public key in frontend

Tags: json, dart, jwt, rsa, jwk

hi i'm trying to import a jwk generated from the server in my flutter app

```
var signeature =
    JsonWebSignature.fromCompactSerialization(response.body);
var payload = signeature.unverifiedPayload;
Map<String, dynamic> key = jsonDecode(payload.jsonContent["jwk"]);
PublicKey rsakey = RsaPublicKey(e: key['e'], n: key['n']);
Jwk jwk = Jwk.fromPublicKey(rsakey);
```

the problem is that `RsaPublicKey` requires `e` and `n` as `List<int>` but my keys has no `List<int>`

```
{additionalData: {}, alg: null, crv: null, d: null, dp: null, dq: null, e: AQAB, k: null, keyId: null, keyOps: [], kid: null, kty: RSA, n: rnuxgDk-9cWCeehBWotGz2YkXpu6_0wPVlVkip1EHUdpWXpX4vAvOeclNIrEYzMOrBIUvwLptk-FMsOgpdvxjWtHFfanv60xsTLAV6ZXMO-R2Ojzgpv4izFvyduC2MihkoMBL_evo9JltMfX2ZSXIwwZoqPed2v9GI9aIjhhKZqju-anVjt3n6dHxlLyduaoatZbD7tzjo-bPeO8o1rycBQFCncgdQ9ST3C6CmZYOUpCFF9ojb4vZtvmIcbtl9Hyud9dOViufE1vPrpJq0ZjeR_ovtApfaQKsi3YJhn77Uwg_XxzgE-SPq960skNwd0IFpyiuxcOvRRIvL6N_-FCdw, oth: null, p: null, q: null, qi: null, use: null, x: null, x5c: [], x5t: null, x5tS256: null, x5u: null, y: null, keySize: 2048, hasPrivateKey: false, cryptoProviderFactory: {cryptoProviderCache: {}, customCryptoProvider: null, cacheSignatureProviders: true, signatureProviderObjectPoolCacheSize: 4}}
```

is it possible to convert `e` and `n` into a `List<int>`?

I tried using other defined PublicKey but on the import it asks for bigint instead of list but i still don't know how to convert it into bigint anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`e` and `n` are base 64 url safe encoded. You can safely convert these values from base 64 to base 10.

- `e`: base64(`AQAB`) <=> base10(`65537`)
- `n`: base64(`rnuxgDk-9cWCeehBWotGz2Yk[...]N_-FCdw`) <=> base10(`3524233685557009967[...]305551728`)

Note: I used https://math.tools/calculator/base/64-10 for these conversions